# Docking Footer to Bottom Outside of Main Div

Tags: html, css, footer

A lot of times the HTML structure for a web page is this:

```
<div id="full">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Mine's a little different:

```
<div id="full">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
</div>
<footer id="footer"></footer><!-- I assume it doesn't matter whether it's a footer or a div  -->
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
}
#full {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
#body {
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Aside from the structure itself, I think it's worth mentioning that:

- The `#header`'s content is pre-known and `#body`'s isn't.
- The `#body` is filling the remaining content after `#header` (I used the `flex` method).

I found a lot of examples but each of them had the `#footer` inside the main container.

My question is:

How do I fix the `#footer` so it'll stay at the bottom?

Comment: `position: fixed;`? -&- You don't need `display: flex` and `flex-direction`

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/hwbgb4v8/

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/077ecd6bc2.png
If you look at the bottom part you'll see a white portion, it shouldn't be. Also, if the table is longer than the footer will just stay at the bottom of the screen, not at the bottom of the page. This is the result of your suggestion.

Comment: So apply the flex method to the `body`. https://jsfiddle.net/hwbgb4v8/2/

Comment: Didn't fix it, still the same

Comment: It works in the jsfiddle... You need to add `display:flex; flex-direction: column;` to `body`, and `flex-grow: 1` to `#full` .. That's 1 layer up.

Comment: There's still the extra white part at the bottom...

Comment: Well I'm not a magician. In the snippet there doesn't seem to be a problem. So you need to check what makes that white part on your end on the full page... Is it some margin you have added somewhere? Is it maybe a background? Without the full code, nobody can help you further. I'm sorry.

Comment: Your mark up is **invalid**. `<div id="header">` is not the same as `<header>` and `<div id="body">` is not the same as `<body>` finally `<div id="footer">` is not the same as `<footer>` and all of these elements would be rendered inside the <body> tag by any modem browser. Please kindly note that `<header>` and `<head>` are **two different things**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a solution to what I wanted, but I solved it by changing the structure.

As I mentioned in my question, my `#body` is filling the remaining space after the `#header`, and everything has to be on top of it (visually, at least), including the footer.

I changed my structure so that the `#footer` is inside the `#body`, at the end of it.

That doesn't sound like the right solution but it works for me without causing any other problems.